# PowerBI DISTINCT SUMX in DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I want to use the SUMX function in combination with DISTINCT

| ProductGroup | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y | product1 | 5 |
| Y | product2 | 4 |
| Y | product1 | 5 |
| X | product3 | 3 |

I want result to be 12 (so we use Sales for product1 only once)
I tried to do something like this but it will take only 5 or 4 (depends on MAX, MIN functions) for Group Y.

```
= SUMX(
          DISTINCT(
                     Table[product1]
           ),
           MAXX(DISTINCT(Table[product1]), MAX(Table[Sales]))
)
```

Please help me, haven't found any solutions yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SumDistinct =
SUMX (
    DISTINCT ( Table1[Product] ),
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( Table1[Sales] ) )
)
```

The CALCULATE turns the row context (the Product) into a filter context (otherwise it would take the max over the whole column).

Comment: It works, thank you! But is there any way to do sum of sales of all groups? Because now it removes all not unique sales, as I can see.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. Should this be a separate post?